# How can I make three little curly braces for this table?

Tags: tables, multirow, brackets

I have copied what I wrote in LaTeX and I will also attach a picture of what I want to achieve.

Desired result:

[image]

What I wrote so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1.5cm}||p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}||p{1.5cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Lepton Classification} \\
\hline
$l$ & $Q$ & $L_e$ & $L_\mu$ & $L_\tau$\\
\hline
$e$  & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
$\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
$\mu$ & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
$\nu_\mu$ & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
$\tau$ & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
$\nu_\tau$ & 0  & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

<sub>I looked up several posts. However, I could not adjust the solutions to my problem.</sub>

Comment: Quick suggestion, please use `\usepackage{multirow}` and `\multirow....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[first-row,first-col,vlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
  & \Block{1-5}{Lepton Classification} \\ \Hline
\RowStyle[bold]{}
  & $l$ & $Q$ & $L_e$ & $L_\mu$ & $L_\tau$ \\ \Hline
\Block[l]{2-1}{First generation\hspace*{3mm}}
  & $e$  & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  & $\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \Hline
\Block[l]{2-1}{Second generation\hspace*{3mm}}
  & $\mu$ & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  & $\nu_\mu$ & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \Hline
\Block[l]{2-1}{Third generation\hspace*{3mm}}
  & $\tau$ & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  & $\nu_\tau$ & 0  & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \Hline
\CodeAfter [sub-matrix/left-xshift=2.5mm,sub-matrix/extra-height=-4pt]
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{2-1}{3-1}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{4-1}{5-1}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{6-1}{7-1}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by several compilations? I tried it and I get some errors, like "undefined control sequence". If you happen to know how it can be solved, it would be very useful !

Comment: During the first compilation, some informations are written in the `aux` file. They are used at the next compilation, etc. Some tools, such as `latexmk`, directly do the right number of compilations. If you use Overleaf, the right number of compilations is done.

Comment: **Remark about Overleaf**: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Yes, I use Overleaf. Thank you for your answer. I tried to just add ```nicematrix.sty``` to my repository but I guess I included it wrongly. Probably this will take lots of time for me to go in depth...

Comment: I have a quick question, what should I use to make the letters in the first row bold? I tried `\mathbf{}` however it did not work, I also tried `\boldsymbol`

Comment: @somerandomguest: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `NiceArray` of `nicematrix`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[\NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}
\begin{NiceArray}{c@{\hspace*{2em}}cccccc}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
&& \Block{1-5}{\text{Lepton Classification}} &&&& \\
&& l & Q & L_e & L_\mu & L_\tau \\
\Block{2-1}{\text{First generation}} && e  & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
&& \nu_e & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\Block{2-1}{\text{Second generation}} && \mu & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
&& \nu_\mu & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\Block{2-1}{\text{Third generation}} && \tau & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
&& \nu_\tau & 0  & 0 & 0 & 1
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {3,5,7} \draw (\x-|3) -- (\x-|last);
\foreach \x in {4,5,6,7} \draw (2-|\x) -- (last-|\x);
\draw (2-|3) rectangle (last-|last);
\draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] ([shift={(-4pt,2pt)}]5-|2) -- ([shift={(-4pt,-2pt)}]3-|2);
\draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] ([shift={(-4pt,2pt)}]7-|2) -- ([shift={(-4pt,-2pt)}]5-|2);
\draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] ([shift={(-4pt,2pt)}]9-|2) -- ([shift={(-4pt,-2pt)}]7-|2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, perhaps it is better if you shift, a bit, to the right the curly brackets.

Comment: @Sebasiano I agree. Thank you for the comment. It is easy to adjust.

Comment: @polyn , thank you so much for your solution, it's great! But it needs so much knowledge, bruhh! Still have to learn a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I propose this solution with basic tools – the `eqparbox` and `bigdelim` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{l |wc{1.2cm}||wc{1.2cm}|wc{1.2cm}|wc{1.2cm}||wc{1.2cm}| }
\cline{2-6}
 & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Lepton Classification} \\
\cline{2-6}
& $l$ & $Q$ & $L_e$ & $L_\mu$ & $L_\tau$\\
\cline{2-6}
\ldelim\{{2}{*}[\eqparbox{A}{First generation}] & $e$ & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 & $\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\[1ex]
\cline{2-6}
\ldelim\{{2}{*}[\eqparbox{A}{Second generation\hspace*{1.5em}}] & $\mu$ & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 & $\nu_\mu$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[1ex]
\cline{2-6}
\ldelim\{{2}{*}[\eqparbox{A}{Third generation}] & $\tau$ & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 & $\nu_\tau$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A warm thanks for the edit, @Sebastiano! Once more, I forgot to check if everything was OK…

Comment: We here are a great community...and it is a very pleasure to help everyone. :-)

Comment: @Bernard , 
Thank you so much for your solution!  Could you please tell me how to adjust the braces a bit more, so that they are shifted a bit downwards? (Since now they do not exactly point where they are supposed to, they are slightly shifted upwards)

Comment: At the end of each group, I added a vertical spacing  of 1ex (`\\[1ex]`). You may change this value, or even suppress these spacings (in this case, each brace touches the next one)? Other tool: cheat a bit and use decimal values in \ldelim,, e.g. `\ldelim\{ {2.25}{*}{…}`

Answer (score 0):

i used the `\multirow` commands (from the multirow package) on a 6th column on the left of your table (for your generations comments). using `\cline{2-6}` instead of `\hline` prevent from having horizontal lines above and below the generations cases.

I have also put your title (Lepton classification) into a different table so it is not surrounded by vertical lines like the rest of your table.

My code :

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Lepton Classification} \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{m{4cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|m{1cm}|}
\cline{2-6}
& $l$ & $Q$ & $L_e$ & $L_\mu$ & $L_\tau$\\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{2}{*}{First Generation} & $e$  & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
& $\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{2}{*}{Second Generation} & $\mu$ & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
& $\nu_\mu$ & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{2}{*}{Third Generation} & $\tau$ & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& $\nu_\tau$ & 0  & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: I don't know about the brackets though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @PierrickMorin !
Thank you for your answer! 
My main problem is unfortunately the braces. Let's wait for someone to answer it and it will be useful for both of us:)